# If statement in makefile

Tags: makefile

I found that I can use ifneq in makefile and I tried to compare 0 and the output of command stat:

```
@for f in `find $(PATH_PAGES) -name *.hbs`; do \
    ifneq "`stat -c '%Y' $$f`" "0";
        //some code here
    endif
done
```

But in terminal I've got an error: ifneq: command not found

Is there a different way to compare this or maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: `-c` is not a portable option to stat, so I'm guessing that you are using it to determine if the file has been modified.  `make` is pretty good at comparing timestamps to determine if a dependency is out of date, and it would probably be better to let `make` evaluate the timestamps.  Also, you will need line continuations (and probably more semi-colons), since make will treat multiple lines as multiple commands.

Comment: So, how can I let `make` determine timestamps? There is a command in that loop and `make` always call this command on each file, even if this file hasn't been modified. So in that loop I use `touch` to change timestamp and now I want to compare time after timestamp that I use `touch --date="1970-01-01 03:00" $$f;` and 0.
I know It's awful solution but I need to edit that makefile and this is my first day with all that makes and makefiles)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case you *don't* want to use Make's `ifneq`, because it does text substitution before handing over the command to the shell, but you have a shell loop that needs to do different things in each iteration depending on the output of a shell command.

Use the shell `if` instead:

```
if [ "`stat -c '%Y' $$f`" != "0" ]; then
    //some code here
fi
```

Comment: Thanks! By the way I added "then" after if condition, and it now works.

Comment: @IvanShcherbakov, right, I forgot that.  I edited the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use makefile's if condition then there should not be [TAB] before the if statement because if you specify [TAB] then it is treated as shell command thats why you are getting error that `ifneq:command not found` its not there in shell.

May be this [Conditionals in Makefile: missing separator error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16770042/conditionals-in-makefile-missing-separator-error/16770163#16770163)
can help in getting better understanding with makefiles

Answer (score 0):

I found that I needed to prepend the `if` with a `@`, and backslashes proved to be necessary as well -

```
@if [ "`stat -c '%Y' $$f`" != "0" ]; then\
    echo hello world;\
fi
```