# getting "*** missing separator. Stop." from makefile, already checked for tabs

Tags: makefile

Here is the makefile, the error is coming from line 5 `ifeq($(PROD),all)`

```
APP=all
LOC=en_US

html: loc
ifeq($(APP),all)
    @for app in apps/*; do echo "Building $app"; grunt --prod $app --loc $(LOC); done
else
    @grunt --prod $(APP) --loc $(LOC)
endif

loc:
ifeq($(LOC),en_US)
    @echo "Building $(LOC)"
else ifeq($(LOC),zh_CN)
    @echo "Building $(LOC)"
else
    @echo "Invalid LOC $(LOC)" && exit 1;
endif
```

From what I can tell from other stackexchange answers, this issue usually occurs when there are missing tabs, but I have checked that there are tabs for all of the `sh` code that needs running

Comment: Are you *sure* you have tabs in the file? Some editors are set to save tabs as spaces.

Comment: yes, using emacs with all tab characters highlighted

Comment: Unrelated but you need to double the `$` in `echo "Building $$app"`, etc. for that to work the way you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16770042/conditionals-in-makefile-missing-separator-error/16770163#16770163

Answer (score 2):

Found it, there have to be spaces after `ifeq` statements.

```
html: loc
ifeq ($APP,all)
```